# Display separate activity on Samsung Galaxy Tab HDMI output

Tags: android

I'm reworking a project where I control LEDs on a miniature model, and display a presentation at the same time on an LCD Monitor above.

I previously had to work with a clunky touch screen laptop/tablet hybrid which was hooked up to an external monitor which showed a presentation slide while it lit up the LED.

I've now developed an android application for the Galaxy Tab 10.1 which controls LEDs on a miniature model via bluetooth, and is hooked up to the monitor via the Samsung HDMI adapter.

My question is, is there anyway to output two separate activities one for the tablet, one for the screen? The current setup just mirrors the screen, but when I open a slide it automatically displays the video in full resolution on the screen so it can be done, but I'm not sure if its an open API (Can't find one!).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from Samsung

> Unfortunately Android itself does not support multiple displays, as
>   stated here: 
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Jxp_9ZtzL60
>   and Samsung also does not extend this functionality.

In that thread it does point out a useful Motorola API to control the HDMI output, shame I've got a load of Samsung tablets!

http://developer.motorola.com/docs/motorola-hdmi-status-api/